# Where do you get inspiration for desktop apps?

Tags: desktop-application, inspiration

There are a lot of sites with inspiration for mobile apps or websites - is there any site with inspiration for desktop apps?
If not - where do you get the inspiration? And examples?

Comment: If you're looking for ideas for what to build, then do some design research, which reveals where people have needs. Create apps that address those needs and support their tasks. (If you're looking for visual inspiration, then this might not be the forum for that.)

Answer (score 1):

To get inspired you can try [dribble with a desktop tag](https://dribbble.com/search?q=desktop) , and UX.SE for desktop application related [questions & solutions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/desktop-application).

For official guidelines:

**Microsoft:** [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/design), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn688964(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps)

**Mac:** [OSXHIGuidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/)